# need sample code for Remove Red Eye from photo in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

[image]

i need like that. Give me some Sample Code for this.

Comment: first show what you have tried.

Comment: Although always nice to know/have resources to a solution for this kind of problem. Stackoverflow is not a tutorial site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Red-iGone](https://github.com/teamdevify/Red-iGone.git)

Hope. its works for you. !!

Comment: tell me another good example for red eye remove?